# loadHTML only returns javascript, it doesn't returns source

Tags: php

I am trying to get HTML content of the page, but when I do that, my file_get_contents only returns piece of JS.

when I use just file_get_contents I can see the content but I am trying to use loadHTML as well. So using the function like below.

```
function getContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
    {
        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);

        $parser = new \DOMDocument();
        $parser->loadHTML($result = mb_convert_encoding($result,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS'));

        return $parser;

    }
```

But this time, I am having `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity` So tried to overcome this problem I used             `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` this but, then I am just returning JS part of page...

How can I overcome issue?

The links is here: https://lions-mansion.jp/MF161037/

Comment: `file_get_contents` downloads whatever a webserver had served. It's not a "problem".

Comment: then the source is JS hidden or something? then is there a way to catch that source and overcome this "ISSUE" @zerkms

Comment: Nothing is hidden, if you want to interpret JS - you need a browser. Take a headless google chrome and fetch a page with it.

Comment: are you sure its `file_get_contents` and not your caching layer or any other processing you are doing? have you tried to var_dump just the straight file_get_contents result? If I try this I do see plenty of html, divs, tables, etc.

Comment: yes you are right if I just do `file_get_contents` I get the content but, when I try to use  `loadHTML` in the function it doesn't return the same way? @imandrewd

Comment: Side note: That `@` on your `file_get_contents` thing suppresses errors. You don't want that - it'll make debugging very frustrating if something is wrong with the URL.